# Regular Expression character set only

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried this : `[fl]ady?[ing] ?[rb]ug!?`
I know `[fl]ad[y]?(ing)? ?[br]ug!?` is an answer

Can this be solved using character sets only? Must match both.

ladybug
fading rug!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should work for you

```
[fl]ad(y|ing)\s?[br]ug?
```

Check out http://www.regexpal.com/

Comment: I'm looking for using square brackets only

Comment: I'm not sure your use-case for not wanting parentheses but this would do what you're looking for then:
`[fl]ady?i?n?g?\s?[br]ug!?`
or
`[fl]ad[y]?[i]?[n]?[g]?\s?[br]ug!?` if you really want those extra brackets...

Comment: It's a coding course I'm taking. The section I'm currently on only involves using square brackets

Comment: Yes, you can solve this using only square brackets. (see my answer). But as a consequence it matches a whole lot other letter combinations. Not sure if I would like this course. ;-)

Comment: Oh, good one!
I think I might even refine it a bit more to
`[fl]ad[giny]+\s*[br]+ug!?`

Comment: Lol, each section is broken down to smaller parts. Each of those parts happen to be short videos. The video I was currently on only talked about character sets and had small exercises associated with that video. So I was trying to play the rules lol

Comment: That's what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Using character sets only? So, it doesn't matter what other letter combinations it matches as well? Mmm. Then

```
[fl]ad[giny]+[\sbrug!]+
```

would do. See: https://regex101.com/r/FJWJyM/1

Comment: Why doesn't this work `[fl]ad[giny] ?[br]ug!?`?

Comment: You need more characters out of [giny]. So [giny]+ would be needed. So [fl]ad[giny]+ ?[br]ug!? would match both. See https://regex101.com/r/kH9Car/1